# Looking for a simple and efficient way to generate random numbers in python so that in every 10 number sequance the numbers won't repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I was wondering if there is an simple and efficient way to generate random numbers in python
so that every sequence of 10 of them will be different numbers.

I tried this option:

```
import random
random.randint(0,100)
```

but after a few generations i've noticed that the generated numbers can repeat one after another
so i tried to use a set of these numbers and it kinda solved the problem
but it leaves some numbers behind which i need to regenerate afterwards if i need a specific amount of randomly generated numbers but after a while i was suggested with another solution:

```
Randlist = random.sample(range(1,101), k=10)
```

which works great but requires a list of integers to hold my 10 different numbers

Is there a way to do it without the list and so it wont be too complex like O(n^2) and above ?

Comment: Sampling from a collection like you do at the end will likely be the most straightforward way. And note that `range` isn't a list. It's an object that holds a few numbers, and calculates its elements by index as they're requested.

Comment: @Carcigenicate even when i do it like this: import random

print(random.sample(range(1,101), k=10), end = ' ') it still prints them as a list..

Comment: Would you accept [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 9] as valid (if unlikely) output? The first 10 do not repeat, but the sequence of 10 starting from the second number includes one repeat.

Comment: @Oli if we are talking about single digit numbers than yes, but i do wonder what will it take to shuffle the next sequence.

Comment: What is the problem with requiring a list?  This is **O(1)** memory and time.

Comment: @Prune i need it as a sequence, or as separate values, when you print it as a list it prints everything inside [ ] with "," and not just numbers.

Comment: Producing the output is merely a matter of formatting.  You objecting to using an auxiliary list.  Why?  Also, note that a list *is* a sequence.

Comment: @Prune fair enough

Answer (score 3):

### Algorithm

```
import random

def randoms():
    while True:
        yield random.randint(0,9)

def no_repeat(source_iter, length):
    seen = set()
    cycle_pos = 0
    while True:        
        n = next(source_iter)
        if n not in seen:
            yield n
            cycle_pos += 1
            seen.add(n)

            if cycle_pos == length:
                seen.clear()
                cycle_pos = 0


rep = no_repeat(randoms(), 10)

print([next(rep) for i in range(100)]) # take 100 items from the `rep` iterator and put them into a list
```

The `randoms` function is a generator that gives an infinite number of random numbers.
The `no_repeat` function is a generator that takes a generator as an argument and filters it so that each section of length 10 has no repeats.

By combining these generators, you can make an iterator that produces random numbers with no repeats in each length 10 sequence.

### Complexity

If you assume that the range of possible random numbers is much larger than the 'cycle length' then it is `O(n)` to generate `n` numbers, since every iteration, you generate a random number, yield it, and add it to the set. Assuming that the set is a hash table, this addition is `O(1)` (as is the check to see if it is in the set). If clearing a set is `O(n)`, then if this is done every 10 operations and takes time proportional to 10, then this is amortized to `O(1)` per iteration.

If smaller ranges of possible numbers are to be considered, then for cycle length `k`, at the beginning of the cycle it is `O(1)` per iteration, then there is a `1/k` probability of a clash, then for the next iteration a `2/k` probability etc. until it resets after `k` iterations.
Thus it is `O(k^2 n)`, but this `k` is fixed (in your case it is always 10), so really it could be considered a constant factor making this equivalent to `O(n)`.

Comment: interesting approach, what is the thime complexity of this?

Comment: @AlexButane edited with some informal thyme complexity stuff :)

Comment: I don't want to be petty, but generating random numbers until you hit one that is valid is way less efficient than just shuffling a list of valid numbers

Comment: @fafl It depends what properties you want your random numbers to have. If you are generating 10 unique numbers from 1 to 10, then it takes about 100 iterations to generate them O(n^2) compared to O(n) time to to create your list of 10 items and O(n) to shuffle them, making shuffling have better complexity.

Comment: However if you want to generate 10 numbers from 1 to 10000, it is extremely unlikely that you will have a collision, so it will be about 10 iterations to generate your numbers. Doing the same thing with shuffling involves about 10000 operations to create the 10000 element list then time propotional to 10000 operations to shuffle the list, then only take 10 elements from it. Also creating a list every iteration of your algorithm will involve allocation, which I suspect adds a large constant factor to the algotithm.

Comment: Neither approach is absolutely better than the other, but it depends what parameters you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably generate the numbers first and then shuffle them in-place. Something like this:

```
import random

numbers = [*range(10)] * 5
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```

Edit: If you want the groups of numbers to stay together, use this instead:

```
import random

result = []
for i in range(5):
  numbers = [*range(10)]
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  result.extend(numbers)
print(result)
```

Comment: what should i put before the *range(10) part?

Comment: I think this will not work, since this generates a list containing 5 ones, 5 twos ... and 5 nines, then shuffles this list. There is no guarantee that the five ones will all be placed in different sections of the list (in fact I think it is unlikely that they will).